# Run animation in background when dataTaskWithURL is processing SWIFT

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch, uianimation

I need to load some posts/images before pushing a view. In my view controller I have something like that:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

     let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:defaultUrlAsString)!) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

          //do stuff
          //load posts

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

              self.performSegueWithIdentifier("splitview", sender: self)

          });
      }

      task.resume()
```

}

In this view, I need to animate many imageviews with an UIAnimation:

```
func animatePulse() {

    let duration = 0.5
    let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse, UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat]

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay:0.0, options: options, animations: {

        self.haloGreenImageView.alpha=1

        }, completion: { animationFinished in

            self.haloGreenImageView.alpha=0.3
    })    
}
```

If I call my animatePulse method in viewDidLoad like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.animatePulse()
}
```

I can see my animation fews seconds when the view appears, **but the animation stops as soon as dataTaskWithURL is called**.

I would like to display my animation as soon as the view appears, while the data are loaded, until the new view is pushed.

Comment: And you have commented out the task so you know it's the cause? What debugging did you do?

Comment: After debugging, the animation stops when performSegueWithIdentifier is called. I suppose it's because the next view is loading (between 3 - 5 sec). I'm not satisfied with that but I don't think there is a solution.

Comment: Show the next view and animate there while waiting